# using matlab surf functions with x size 11 and y size 6

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to use matlab for calculating the approximation of a function using the composite trapezoidal rule, and then displaying the function and approximation using a surf function and a bar3 function. the thing is is that when I try plot the function surf(x,y,Z) I receive and error saying dimension's mismatch.

**my question is how would I get the surf function to plot the 3D graph when my x,y and z arrays differ in size.**

I've tried to create zeros functions of the the x and y array's of the same size and then adding my values to each, then NaN'ing the extra 0's, but as u see each of my arrays start with 0's therefore NaN'ing where i find a zero in my arrays will effect my graph plot. and plus i still get the same error "dimensions mismatch" so i supposed thats because my Z array is bigger than my x and y.

**Any help would be appreciated.**

code for my x and y are:
`

```
 x = linspace(a,b,h); %h being 11 and breaks up the difference because datapoints a   and b into h number of sub intervals

 y = linspace(c,d,k); %k being 6 and breaks up the difference because data points c and d into k number of sub intervals

Z = zeros(h,k);
for i = 1:1:h      
    for j = 1:1:k
    Z(i,j) = f(x(i),y(j));
    end
end
```

surf(x,y,Z);
`

x

```
     0    0.3000    0.6000    0.9000    1.2000    1.5000    1.8000    2.1000    2.4000    2.7000    3.0000
```

y

```
     0    0.6286    1.2571    1.8857    2.5143    3.1429
```

Z

```
     0         0         0         0         0         0
     0    0.1764    0.2854    0.2852    0.1761   -0.0004
     0    0.3528    0.5707    0.5705    0.3522   -0.0008
     0    0.5292    0.8561    0.8557    0.5283   -0.0011
     0    0.7056    1.1415    1.1410    0.7044   -0.0015
     0    0.8820    1.4268    1.4262    0.8804   -0.0019
     0    1.0584    1.7122    1.7115    1.0565   -0.0023
     0    1.2348    1.9975    1.9967    1.2326   -0.0027
     0    1.4112    2.2829    2.2820    1.4087   -0.0030
     0    1.5876    2.5683    2.5672    1.5848   -0.0034
     0    1.7640    2.8536    2.8525    1.7609   -0.0038
```

Error using surf (line 75)
Data dimensions must agree.

Error in CompositeTrapazoidal>btnSolve_Callback (line 167)
surf(x,y,Z);

Answer (score 1):

Try `surf(x,y,Z');` (because `x`'s length should match the `Z`'s column count)

Comment: Thanks so much! aaah how i love programming, sit on a problem for hours just to find out that u are missing a ' ... :)

Comment: Until a reliable implementation of "Do What I Mean" language, we have to do with what is available. :-)